# jquery one div on top of another div by 100px

Tags: jquery, position

I would like to position one div on top of another div by 100px at all time, even when I am scrolling. I tried to use the jquery .position but couldn't get it to work.

something

something

Comment: "something something" ??    Where is the code you've tried, can we see you html/css?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a bottom margin to the top div:

```css
   #divOne {
     margin-bottom: 100px;
   }
   div {
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     background: #eee;
   }
```

```html
<div id="divOne">Top Div</div>
<div id="divTwo">Bottom Div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just insert a div in another div like this:

```
<div class="motherDiv" style="position:relative;">
 <div class="childDiv" style="position:absolute;top:-100px;"></div>
</div>
```

The motherDiv's position is "relative" and you set the childDiv to "absolute". Whatever happens with the motherDiv, will be applied to the childDiv, which is absolute to the motherDiv =)